# Grouping by one column and summing multiple other columns in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm found a very ugly way to do what I need (currently just in the Rails view, I'll move it later), which is basically to find all the articles of a particular user, group them into their individual publications, and then sum the share counts of all of the articles the user has added for that publication.

...But it's not pretty. If there's a better way to do this, can someone advise?

```
  =@user.articles.group(:publication).map do |p|
    =p.publication
    =@user.articles.where("publication = ?", p.publication).sum(:twitter_count)
    =@user.articles.where("publication = ?", p.publication).sum(:facebook_count)
    =@user.articles.where("publication = ?", p.publication).sum(:linkedin_count)
```

This gives the output (e.g.) NYT 12 18 14 BBC 45 46 47 CNN 75 54 78, which is pretty much what I need.

However, at present, it's also outputting some extra stuff on the end - "[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5] sum(:twitter_count)" - I think this is to do with the .map but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

Change `=` by `-` in first line.

```
- @user.articles.group(:publication).map do |p|
```

Comment: Thanks - this clears up the additional stuff at the end. But I was also looking for suggestions to make the whole block cleaner - if you have any, they'd be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You are right. `.map` is creating new array.

Substitute `=` with `-` on the first line. (credits goes to [juanpastas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16374026/1136008), I did not remember HAML)

[Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) for `#map`:

> Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
a.map { |x| x + "!" }   #=> ["a!", "b!", "c!", "d!"]
a                       #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, and your comment - I've upvoted his answer. Any suggestions to make the overall code block better welcome too though.