# PG::Error in GROUP BY clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I couldn't think of a better way to refactor the below code (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373950/grouping-by-one-column-and-summing-multiple-other-columns-in-rails/16374026?noredirect=1#16374026)), though I know it's very ugly. However, it's throwing a Postgres error (not with SQLite):

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: 
PG::Error: ERROR:  
column "articles.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

The query itself is:

```
SELECT "articles".* 
FROM "articles" 
WHERE "articles"."user_id" = 1 
GROUP BY publication
```

Which comes from the following view code:

```
=@user.articles.group(:publication).map do |p|
  =p.publication
  =@user.articles.where("publication = ?", p.publication).sum(:twitter_count)
  =@user.articles.where("publication = ?", p.publication).sum(:facebook_count)
  =@user.articles.where("publication = ?", p.publication).sum(:linkedin_count)
```

In SQLite, this gives the output (e.g.) NYT 12 18 14 BBC 45 46 47 CNN 75 54 78, which is pretty much what I need.

How can I improve the code to remove this error?

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Older PostgreSQL versions didn't realise that when you `GROUP BY` the `PRIMARY KEY` you're implicitly grouping by all columns. If `publication` is *not* the primary key then the generated SQL is totally wrong and doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It's PG Version: 9.1.9, running on Heroku

Comment: and *is* `publication` the primary key? If it isn't that generated code is nonsensical.

Comment: And yes, sorry, `publication` isn't the primary key, `id` is. But I thought it was OK to group by other fields?

Comment: Yes - but as the error message explicitly states, you must either `group by` a field or use it in an aggregate expression. So you can't just `select table.*`. How would PostgreSQL know which result to return for a row when there's more than one possibility? Pick one randomly? It won't do that. Some other DBs disobey the standard and execute such incorrect queries, giving unpredictable/ill-defined results where PostgreSQL refuses to execute it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Craig's answer explains the issue well. Active Record will `select *` by default, but you can override it easily:

```
@user.articles.select("publication, sum(twitter_count) as twitter_count").group(:publication).each do |row|
  p row.publication # "BBC"
  p row.twitter_count # 45
end
```

Comment: Yes, this code works. I had to add some more selections in there ('sum(facebook_count) as facebook_count, sum(linkedin_count) as linkedin_count') but it returns all the data I need and it's nicer than my effort. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I never would've got that as I don't speak ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 7):

When using `GROUP BY` you cannot `SELECT` fields that are not either part of the `GROUP BY` or used in an aggregate function. This is specified by the SQL standard, though some databases choose to execute such queries anyway. Since there's no single correct way to execute such a query they tend to just pick the first row they find and return that, so results will vary unpredictably.

It looks like you're trying to say:

"For each publication get me the sum of the twitter, facebook and linkedin counts for that publication".

If so, you could write:

```
SELECT publication,
       sum(twitter_count) AS twitter_sum,
       sum(linkedin_count) AS linkedin_sum,
       sum(facebook_count) AS facebook_sum
FROM "articles" 
WHERE "articles"."user_id" = 1 
GROUP BY publication;
```

Translating that into ActiveRecord/Rails ... up to you, I don't use it. It looks like it's pretty much what you tried to write but ActiveRecord seems to be mangling it, perhaps trying to execute the sums locally.

Comment: Thanks - I've upvoted this for the explanation. But I can't see what's causing my Rails code to behave this way, and that's where I really need to fix it. I will try executing them locally though, good idea.

Comment: @Nick ugh, no; I suspect ActiveRecord is *trying* to grab data to then do its own filtering on locally but I don't think that's a particularly good idea. Why not just use native SQL if ActiveRecord's getting it wrong?

Comment: Actually, can't you just write: =p.publication =sum(p.twitter_count) =sum(p.facebook_count) =sum(p.linkedin_count) ? (I don't speak ActiveRecord so that may be gibberish; point is I suspect the WHERE clause is confusing it since a WHERE doesn't make sense along with that GROUP BY)

Comment: Unfortunately not - it throws an undefined method error when I do that (and several other permutations). Although it would be much cleaner.